# A characterization of local objects in model categories

Tags: reference-request, ct.category-theory, model-categories, bousfield-localization

Let $\mathcal{M}$ be a model category and $S$ a set of cofibrations between cofibrant objects. Then every $S$-[local object](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/local+object#definition_in_model_categories) has the right lifting property with respect to $S$. The converse does not hold in general, but it does under suitable closure conditions on $S$. I think the following should be enough:

> **Proposition:** Suppose that, for every map $f : A \to B$ in $S$, there are cylinder objects $C(A)$ and $C(B)$ and a morphism of cylinder objects $C(A) \to C(B)$ such that the map $C(A) \amalg_{(A \amalg A)} (B \amalg B) \to C(B)$ belongs to $\mathrm{cof}(J \cup S)$, where $J$ is the class of trivial cofibrations of $\mathcal{M}$. Then a fibrant object of $\mathcal{M}$ is $S$-local if and only if it has the right lifting property with respect to $S$.

I can propably prove this proposition myself, but I'd prefer not to write down the proof. So, I'd like to know whether such a proposition appears in the literature (I could not find such a result in Hirschhorn's book). Alternatively, I will accept a proof of this proposition if it is short and slick.

Comment: It appears that you are asking what conditions should be imposed on S so that S is a set of generating acyclic cofibrations for the left Bousfield localization of M with respect to S.  (This is not quite true literally, since you do not require M to be left proper and are also inquiring about fibrant objects, not fibrations in general.)  This is difficult and there is no simple answer.  That being said, you could use Definition 5.5.4.5 in Lurie's Higher Topos Theory to get such conditions (you need to adjust his definition to the case of cofibrations between cofibrant objects, though).

Comment: @DmitriPavlov A set that recognizes local objects is easier to describe than a set of generating trivial cofibrations. We can always take the set $\widetilde{A} \otimes \Delta^n \amalg_{\widetilde{A} \otimes \partial \Delta^n} \widetilde{B} \otimes \partial \Delta^n \to \widetilde{B} \otimes \Delta^n$ for all $A \to B$ in $S$ (using Hirschhorn's notation). Moreover, if $S$ is closed under this construction, then it already recognizes $S$-local objects. But this condition is too strong. The one I gave in the question is essentially a special case with $n = 1$. I believe it should be enough.

Comment: If you are indeed only interested in fibrant objects and assume the existence of a simplicial enrichment (or use framings as a substitute), then the above formula with a pushout product will suffice.  But sticking to the case n=1 essentially amounts to demanding surjectivity of RHom(B,X)→RHom(A,X) (where X is an S-local object) on π_0 and π_1, and it seems unlikely that surjectivity for π_n with n>1 can somehow follow from the case n=1.

Comment: @DmitriPavlov Well, I assume that $S$ is _closed_ under this construction. If we iterate it, we should get surjectivity for all $n$. Basically, the iteration of this construction should give us _cubical_ framings. So, this might be one way to prove this, but then we need to compare cubical $\mathrm{Hom}$-sets with simplicial ones and this looks like a rather tedious proof. I also think that it might be possible to proof this directly without appealing to cubical framings, but I didn't try this since I hope it was already done.

Comment: Also, I don't literally assume that $S$ is closed under construction. I assume a weaker condition that the map belongs to $\mathrm{cof}(J \cup S)$. I'm not sure about that, it might be too weak. If this is the case, it'd be fine to replace the condition with the stronger one.

Comment: If you do close S under such an operation, then your conjecture is correct as stated.  First, observe that applying this operation n times amounts to taking the pushout product with the inclusion of the boundary of an n-cube into an n-cube.  (Assuming the model category is simplicial, otherwise just use framings.)  The right lifting property with respect to such a set boils down to right lifting property of Hom(B,X)→Hom(A,X) (which is already guaranteed to be a fibration between fibrant objects in simplicial sets) with respect to the cubical boundary inclusions.

Comment: Any fibration of Kan complexes that has a right lifting property with respect to all cubical boundary inclusions is necessarily surjective on all homotopy groups, so must be a weak equivalence.

Comment: @DmitriPavlov That's the idea that I had in mind, but this looks more like a sketch of a proof to me. I'd like to see a proof written in more detail. And I'm not sure that this proof applies to the situation when the map belongs only to $\mathrm{cof}(J \cup S)$ and not $S$ itself.

Comment: I think the weaker condition also suffice at least in the enriched case since we can show that if $S$ is closed under this construction, then so is $\mathrm{cof}(J \cup S)$ using usual adjunction argument. Anyway, as I said I can finish the proof myself, but I'd rather give a reference to an existing proof.